# Making "credits" singular?

Tags: word-usage

I know that "credits" is a plural noun when referring to a list of staff members, but are there situations where it is acceptable or preferable to use the singular form?

Cases I have in mind:

- Post-credit scene. (The scene after the credits)
- Display the current credit name. (One name from the credits)
- Graphics for credit scenes. (Graphics shared by all of the scenes that involve credits)
- Start the current credit scene. (A scene displaying a number of credited people. )

Assume that rewriting these sentences is not option.

Comment: Can you explain what a "credit scene" is here?

Comment: One of the many scenes that involve credits. I'm referring to a game, sorry for omitting this fact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The singular use of the word credit is perfectly acceptable - someone might say "I got a credit on that movie" for example, meaning that their name appeared in the credits.

eg http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/credit

> 3.2: (also credit title) [count noun] (usually credits) An item in a list displayed at the beginning or end of a film or television programme, acknowledging a contributor’s role: the closing credits finished rolling

Similarly a scene featuring a single credit could be called a "credit scene", and the scene intended to come immediately after it could be called a "post-credit scene".  I suppose the entire credits sequence would be made of of "credit scenes" and some other scenes which didn't feature credits.

So, I think all the phrases you mention are totally fine, with the disclaimer that **domain conventions beat all**.  That is to say, if a "credit scene" is typically called something else within the domain/industry in question (movies, video games or whatever) then that is what you should call it, regardless of what else might make more grammatical sense.

EDIT - in answer to the question edits.

A scene after the credits should most intuitively be called "The post credits scene".  However, this is a bit awkward to say, due to the "ts-space-s" transition not being very easy to manage: people will generally either struggle through the tongue-twister or just give up and say "credit scene" instead.  So, I think all the phrases you list are fine as is.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed, general answer, that was appreciated. But would you mind stating whether you'd opt for plural or singular for each of the four cases I've listed?

Comment: Well that depends whether there is one or more credits being discussed in each case.

Comment: In a nutshell: 1) The scene after the credits, 2) One name from the credits, 3) Graphics shared by all of the scenes that involve credits, 4) A scene displaying a number of credited people.

Comment: Put this information in the question please.

Comment: I've edited the original post.